# Excel/VBA Macro ClearContents in column if value smaller than 10000, open/save in new file/close

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly new to macro's, but I want to write a macro that opens a .csv file. Then, clears cell contents if the value is smaller than 10000 in a certain column. Then, save it and put it in a new csv file. My script is a mix of several topics on Stackoverflow.

I tried to write it and came to this:

```
Sub RemoveSmallValues()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myfilename As String

myfilename = "C:\Snapshot.csv"
'~~> open the workbook and pass it to workbook object variable
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myfilename)

Dim r As Range, N As Long
Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B10")
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To N
    BB = Cells(i, "B").Value
    If BB <= 10000 Then Range(BB).ClearContents
    End If
Next i

Dim newfilename As String
newfilename = "C:\SnapshotBB.csv"
'~~> If you are saving it in a format other than .xlsx,
'~~> you have to be explicit in the FileFormat argument
 wb.SaveAs newfilename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
 wb.Close

 End Sub
```

It would be great if you can help me!

Comment: I suspect you get an error here `Range(BB).ClearContents`? You can use `Range("B" & i")` instead. Range() requires a cellreference, where `BB` is a cellvalue.

Comment: Welcome. What has been the issue when you tried this code? What do ypu need help with in the code posted?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the below. I wasn't sure on some of the values that you wanted, so please TEST this before using on LIVE data.

To use this code. Please copy and paste the below into a MODULE.

I have also made a lot of assumptions, such as:

1. There are no BLANK cells in column C for the ROW COUNT
2. There are NO headers in your original CSV file (please see the comments for adjustments if this is not true).

Thanks

```
Sub RemoveSmallValues()

Dim myfilename As String
Dim myfilepath As String
Dim newfilename As String
Dim N As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim cellvalue As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'The above is just standard lines that I normally put into my code, enchances the speed of the macro.

myfilepath = "C:\Snapshot.csv"
myfilename = "Snapshot.csv"

Workbooks.Open (myfilepath)
Workbooks(myfilename).Activate 'Makes SnapShot.csv the active workbook

N = Range("C1", Range("C1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
'counts the number of rows untill cell is BLANK, based on your code I used Column C.
'If your columns have headers then you will need to make this C2. Otherwise your headers will be included and will create a datatype error on CELLVALUE

For i = 1 To N 'Again if your columns have hearders, then i will need to be i = 2
  cellvalue = Cells(i, 2).Value
  If cellvalue <= 10000 Then Cells(i, 2).ClearContents
Next i

newfilename = "C:\SnapshotBB" 'new file path and file name without extension.

Workbooks(myfilename).SaveAs newfilename, FileFormat:=xlCSV 'Save the file with extension CSV
ActiveWorkbook.Close False 'Close the workbook without saving, as you have already saved the workbook with line before.

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Will.D I used the code and adjusted it a little for the headers as you told. I do have BLANK cells. Is that hard to overcome? I have changed to C2 etc. but I get a type mismatch error on this line:  cellvalue = Cells(i, 2)   does it need to be cellvalue = Cells(I= 2)?

Comment: So it does contains blank values, which I want to keep and I only want to keep values tarting with text. See column: DE0006289473   
2560
2575
2596
2599
IE00BYZTVV78   
2630
               
476
324
977
1071
1503
1073
1127
2561
2560
IE00BKWQ0G16   
2575
1800
2602
1140
1046
2596
2599
1049
1089
1512
IE00BYZK4552   
2630
1054
LU1681046931   
2647
2675
               
476
324
977

Answer (score 0):

## CSV Nightmare

### Semicolon (;)

The problem is that my system saves `csv` files using the **semicolon** as separator by default. Excel will open the file normally, but VBA will open the file by putting the data from all columns into column `A`. The workaround is the checking for the number of columns. If there is only one column with data, the `OpenText` method is used with `Local:=True`. Now, the **remaining problem** is that VBA will save the file as **comma** separated , no matter if `Local:=True`, so when I open it in Excel, it will open all the columns in column `A`.

### The Code

```
Sub RemoveSmallValues()

    ' Path of Source and Target Files
    Const myPath As String = "D:\Excel\MyDocuments\StackOverflow\MyAnswers\Test"
    Const myFile As String = "Snapshot.csv"     ' Source File Name
    Const newFile As String = "SnapshotBB.csv"  ' Target File Name

    Const myColumn As String = "B"    ' Source/Target Column
    Const myLRColumn As String = "C"  ' Last-Row Column Letter
    Const FR As Long = 1              ' First Row Number
    Const cCrit As Long = 10000       ' Criteria Value

    Dim wb As Workbook    ' Source Workbook
    Dim rng As Range      ' Cell Ranges
    Dim LR As Long        ' Last Row
    Dim BB As Long        ' Current Value
    Dim i As Long         ' Source Worksheet Row Counter
    Dim FPath As String   ' Full Path

    ' Check if Source Workbook is already open.
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        ' Source Workbook is open, stop looping.
        If wb.Name = myFile Then Exit For
    Next

    ' Calculate Full Path.
    FPath = myPath & "\" & myFile

    ' Check if Source Workbook is not open.
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        ' Handle error if Source Workbook could not be found.
        On Error Resume Next
        ' Create a reference to Source Workbook.
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FPath)
        ' Check if Source Workbook could not be found.
        If Err Then   ' Inform user and exit.
            MsgBox "The file '" & myFile & "' could not be found in folder '" _
                    & myPath & "'.", vbCritical, "File not found"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

    ' Calculate Last Column in Source Worksheet.
    Set rng = wb.ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, xlWhole, _
            xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    ' Check if all values are in first column.
    If rng.Column = 1 Then
        ' Open Source Workbook as delimited file.
        Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=FPath, _
                DataType:=xlDelimited, Local:=True
        ' Create a reference to Source Workbook.
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        ' Calculate Last Column in Source Worksheet.
        Set rng = wb.ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, xlWhole, _
                xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
        ' Check if all values are still in first column.
        If rng.Column = 1 Then   ' Inform user and exit.
            MsgBox "The file '" & myFile & "' in folder '" & myPath _
                    & "' is of an unsupported format.", vbCritical, _
                    "Unsupported format"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    With wb.ActiveSheet
        ' Calculate Last Row in Source Worksheet.
        LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, myLRColumn).End(xlUp).Row
        ' Loop through rows of Source Worksheet.
        For i = FR To LR
            ' Check if the value in current cell is a number.
            If IsNumeric(.Cells(i, myColumn).Value) Then
                ' Write value of current cell to Current Value.
                BB = .Cells(i, myColumn).Value
                ' Check if Current Value meets Criteria.
                If BB <= cCrit Then .Cells(i, myColumn).ClearContents
            End If
        Next
        On Error Resume Next
        ' Save modified Source File as Target File.
        ' Note: This will save the file as COMMA separated anyway, no matter
        '       of the value of Local. Should be investigated.
        .SaveAs Filename:=myPath & "\" & newFile, _
                FileFormat:=xlCSV ', Local:=True ' This doesn't seem to help.
        ' Close Target File.
        .Parent.Close False
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    ' Inform user of success.
    MsgBox "Operation finished successfully.", vbInformation, "Success"

 End Sub
```

Comment: Hi VBasic2008 thanks! this code copies the file to a new workbook, however it does not change the values in the column. This is the column that I need to change: I want to keep the blanks but remove the digits, however not when it starts with text, I want to keep it.

Sec Num        
DE0006289473   
2560
2575
2596
2599
IE00BYZTVV78   
2630
               
476
324
977
1071
1503
1073
1127
2561
2560
IE00BKWQ0G16   
2575
1800
2602
1140
1046
2596
2599
1049
1089
1512
IE00BYZK4552   
2630
1054
LU1681046931   
2647
2675
               
476
324
977
1071
1503